# Why does the page go to the address of the php file when closing the alert?

Tags: javascript, php, html

On my page when we click on the STOP button of the java script alert we are immediately directed to the address of the php file. But I want to direct to another page, how do I go to another page?

```
 <input id="sendMessageButton" type="submit" value="Enviar"  onclick="functionAlert();">
```

```js
var el = document.getElementById('contactForm');

el.addEventListener('submit', function(){
    return confirm('your message?');
}, true);
```

Comment: stop button? You mean cancel on the confirm?

Comment: we need more code, html where you have the button definition for example.

Comment: Now I put the code for the submit button. The idea is to click on the alert STOP button to go to another page or stay on the same page.

Comment: You have a crude javascript implementation... so I may be off here (Im spoiled)... but I think you need to get rid of the `onclick="functionAlert();"` on an `<input>` element, and add a `onsubmit="functionAlert();"` to the `<form>` element. The "true/false" needs to apply to submitting, not clicking.

Comment: For now nothing done, clicking on STOP in the alert continues to redirect to the PHP address page contact_me.php